# How can one enable sharing for a mounted volume via command line? (2 Macs)

Tags: osx

I am trying to remotely enable "sharing" on a volume connected to a remote host. So, in other words, from my local machine I'm trying to ssh into another machine where a volume is already mounted. However, I want access to this mounted volume via afp. So how can I enable sharing on this remote volume to get access to it via afp on my local machine?

I've seen commands for other features but not sharing a volume. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107308/mount-shared-drive-via-afp-in-terminal